# How to make a Facebook-image-style web design using CSS3?

Tags: css

For a client I want to make a design with CSS, which looks like the facebook-image-container, like this: http://pho.to/bGEg79. Does anyone know how I can do this? The general idea is to make a box, centered on the page, with the left half of the box being a picture, and the right half containing the navigation and content. Is this possible with CSS(3)? If yes, how can I do that?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: I have made a centralized box, but the problem I'm having is both to make the picture be the half and the content be the other half, and to make the box stay the same size, with scrolling inside the box, instead of the box constantly changing size when more or less content is added. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: Please post relevant code with specific details of where you require help

Comment: Other than posting code you already have, you should maybe break your question up to several questions. How to center a box on the page? and How to divide a box into two parts? are both valid questions (already answered), while How to build Facebook's image viewer? is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the basic layout and you could customise the dimensions: http://dabblet.com/gist/2406917

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I want, I'll try that!